# Prove $a+2a^2+3a^3<6a^6$ for $a>1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I feel like this is way easier than my work until now has shown, but I'm stuck and don't even know what to try.

This isn't supposed to be too hard and I know that I'm not supposed to use any special algebraic identities, just basic things. So I tried subtracting terms from the left side from the right side to work backwards, for e.g: $a+2a^2+3a^3<6a^6\implies a+3a^3<3a^3(2a^3-1)$, but this has gotten me nowhere. I also noticed that the inequality is $a+2a^2+3a^3<a\times2a^2\times3a^3$, but I didn't know what to do with that either.

Comment: Use the fact that for $n<m$ and $a>1$ we have $a^{n}<a^{m}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $a < a^6$, $a^2 < a^6$, $a^3 < a^6$ for $a > 1$.

Comment: Oh my ******* God. Of course. Love it when I get blocked and think too far. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$
6a^6 -3a^3-2a^2-a=(6a^4 + 6a^3 + 6a^2 + 3a + 1)(a - 1)a>0
$$
for all $a>1$.

Comment: You complicated it too much (as I did in my attempts), but at least it worked for you, thanks.

Comment: All they did was factorise the result by realising the polynomials obvious roots at $0$ and $1$?